# jQuery - Listening element removal live

Tags: jquery, live

Is is possible to listen element removals from DOM with a jQuery live event?

I need something like:

```
$('body').on('remove', '.selector', function() {
  console.log('Element removed.');
});
```

But it is not working :(

Answer (score 4):

Maybe what you're looking for:

```
$.fn.customRemove = function () {
    $(this).remove();
    console.log('Element removed.');
};

$('.selector').customRemove(); // you will get the log automatically
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this not resolves my problem. I want to make a general listener which handles all the removed elements (in the standard way), not to hack manually the original codes.